# Let $f:D \rightarrow D$ be a holomorphic function such that f has a zero of order $N\geq 1$ at the origin, then show that $|f(z)|\leq |z|^N$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $f:D \rightarrow D$ be a holomorphic function such that f has a zero of order $N\geq 1$ at the origin, then show that $|f(z)|\leq |z|^N$ $\forall z\in D$, where $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}| |z|<1\}$

I tried to use Schwarz's lemma inductively here. I showed that $f^n(D)\subseteq D$, but then I don't know how to approach it

Comment: If $f^n$ means the $n$th power of $f$ then $f^n(D)\subset D$ is clear, but I don't see how it helps. If it means the $n$th derivative of $f$ it's not true that $f^n(D)\subset D$.

Comment: In any case, for $N=1$ this is just the Schwarz Lemma. A simple modification of the proof does the case $N\ge1$. (I'm **not** referrring to an inductive argument! Use the Maximum Modulus Theorem to show that $|f(z)/z^N|\le1$, exactly as in the proof for $N=1$.)

Comment: Yes, thanks @MartinR